# Draw table from js file using js

Tags: arrays

I am trying to display all info from an array to a table. This is my javascript array:

**JS**

```
let tableUsers = [
    {name: "Jose", age: "22", Country: "Spain"},
    {name: "Jon", age: "25", Country: "France"},
    {name: "Jacob", age: "36", Country: "Italy"}
]
```

Comment: If you fix your indenting to match up with `{ .... }` blocks, you'll see that `rad` is defined _inside_ the `for` loop, but `table.appendChild(rad)` is _outside_ the loop, so can't see it. (Even if you didn't have the error, you would only be adding a row _once_, when you want to add a row _for each item_.)

Comment: Ah, I see. When put the ´table.appendChild(rad)´ inside nothing is displayed. hmm

Comment: That's because you haven't put _the table as a whole_ anywhere on the page. Presumably you wanted to put it inside the div you've selected into `tableUsers`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding of variable definition.
In ES6, we use let keyword to define variable and is valid in the scope of bracket in which it is defined.
So the code should be following.

```
let tableUsers = document.getElementById("tableDiv");

function drawTable(){
let table = document.createElement("table");
let tableHead = document.createElement("thead");
let colHeads = ["column1", "column2"];

for (let header of colHeads){
    let celle = document.createElement("th")
    celle.innerHTML = header;
    tableHead.appendChild(celle);
}
table.appendChild(tableHead)

let rad; // defined out of the for loop 

for(let x of info){
    rad = document.createElement("tr");

    let firstname = document.createElement("td");
    firstname.innerHTML = x.name.first;
    rad.appendChild(firstname);

    }

table.appendChild(rad)
}
```

drawTable()